# Finding the matrix of a linear transformation from an upper triangular matrix to an upper triangular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question that I am trying to solve is as follows:

> Find the matrix $A$ of the linear transformation
>   $T(M)=
> \begin{bmatrix} 
> 7 & 3 \\ 
> 0 & 1 
> \end{bmatrix}
> M$
>   from $U^{2×2}$ to $U^{2×2}$ (upper triangular matrices) with respect to the basis
>   $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 
> 1 & 0 \\ 
> 0 & 0 
> \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$
>
> $A=\begin{bmatrix} \cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\ \cdot&\cdot&\cdot\end{bmatrix}$

I don't know how to interpret this question. I would have thought that the matrix $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 
7 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ because that is the matrix which defines the linear transformation $T$. I am surprised that the required answer is $A\in M_{3\times 3}$. How can a basis with elements $\in M_{2\times 2}$ form a matrix $\in M_{3\times 3}$?

Comment: Upper triangular matrices are a three dimensional vector space. But I don't understand your question. Usually $U$ indicates unitary matrices.

Comment: Has three dimensions got anything to do with $A\in M_{3\times 3}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upper triangular matrices

$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
0&c
\end{bmatrix}
$

form a vector space with canonical basis:

$
e_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
e_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
e_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$

that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ by:

$
e_1\rightarrow\vec e_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
e_2\rightarrow\vec e_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
e_3\rightarrow \vec e_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Your linear transformation $T$ is defined as a matrix multiplication:

$
T(M)=\begin{bmatrix}
7&3\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
0&c
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
7a&7b+3c\\
0&c
\end{bmatrix}
$
so, in this canonical representation, it is given by the matrix $T_e$ such that:

$
T_e\vec M=\begin{bmatrix}
7&0&0\\
0&7&3\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
7a\\
7b+3c\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
$

Now you want a representation of the same transformation in  a new basis:

$
e'_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow\vec e'_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
e'_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow\vec e'_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
e'_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \vec e'_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$

This transformation of basis is represented by the matrices

$
S=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
S^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$

So the matrix that represents the transformation $T$ in the new basis is:

$
T_{e'}=S^{-1}T_eS=
\begin{bmatrix}
7&0&-3\\
0&7&3\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: When you said "This transformation of basis is represented by the matricies", did you simply put the column vectors $\vec e'_1$, $\vec e'_2$ and $\vec e'_3$ next to each other to get $S$? Or was there a more nuanced way of getting $S$, such as by saying that $\vec e_j= (a_j+b_j+c_j)\vec e'_j$ where $j$ is the number of the column?

Comment: Symply I put the columns ( it's a general rule that you can easely verify by linearity).

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be the basis of $U$, compute $T(X)$, $T(Y)$, $T(Z)$ and express them as a linear combination of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: T(X)=7X; T(Y)=7Y; T(Z)=Z. How does that relate to A?

Comment: A={(7,0,0),(0,7,0),(0,0,1)} take the coefficients as elements of the matrix A.

Comment: I have tried to input all sorts of combinations, such as $\begin{bmatrix} 7 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 0 & 0 \\ 7 & 7 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \text{and} \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 0 & 0 \\ 7 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ but these are still incorrect (I am answering an online test). Btw, welcome to math.stackexchange! What brought you to the site?

Comment: Try A={(7,0,0),(0,7,0),(-3,3,1)} 
Thank you,hopefully my answer will help.Your question brought me here.